# How do I animate a divs percentage width using JQuery's .toggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, animation

So basically I want this to work so that when the user clicks the left most div the left div expands from 25% to 75% and the middle div shrinks from 50% to 0%. Ive tried several approaches but can't seem to get anything to work.

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Skynet</title>

    <!-- css reference-->
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/main.css" type = "text/css">

    <!-- jquery call-->
    <script href="/js/jquery-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--Page animation -->
    <script href="/js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- ui implement-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.4.css" />
    <script href="/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class = "container">
        <!-- left panel-->
        <div class = "left">
                <img src="css/res/skynet_mdlarge.png" alt="Logo" height="130" width="130">
        </div>
        <!-- middle panel-->
        <div class = "mid">

        </div>
        <!-- right panel-->
        <div class = "right">

        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
```

CSS

```
body, html {
height: 100%;
margin: 0px;
}

.container {
height: 100%;

display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
 }

.left {
width: 25%;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
background: url('res/binding_dark_@2X.png') repeat;

}

.mid {
width: 50%;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
background: url('res/tweed_@2X.png') repeat;
}

.right {
width: 25%;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
background: url('res/binding_dark_@2X.png') repeat;

}
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".left").toggle(function(){
        $(".left").animate({width:'75%'},300);
        $(".mid").animate({width:'0%'},300);

    }
    function(){
        $(".left").animate({width:'25%'},300);
        $(".mid").animate({width:'50%'},300);

    });

});
```

Comment: Add a `,` after `expanded = true;}`

Comment: Does your code work without the second function? (delete all from line 6 to line 10)

Comment: No the page stays static. Ive also attempted the same concept using the .click instead of toggle and that didn't work either. Ive also tried using .css instead of .animate to edit the css parts but to no avail.

Comment: Since you're using flexbox would CSS transitions be cool? It would still work in older browsers, just no animation.

Comment: Anything to get this to work. the only reason I was using flex initially was just to keep the div's in line

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would try to keep as much of the styling of things in CSS as possible. I would alter a class on a`.container` element so I have more flexibility with things in CSS.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="mid">Mid</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
}

.left, .mid, .right {
  float: left;
  background-color: #e99;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .3s;
  height: 100%;
}

.left {
  width: 25%;
}
.mid {
  width: 50%;
}
.right {
  width: 25%;
}

.expanded .left {
  width: 75%;
  background-color: #f00;
  color: #fff;
}

.expanded .mid {
  width: 0;
}
```

JS

```
$('.left').on('click', function () {
  $('.container').toggleClass('expanded');
});
```

Note that the animation will not work in older browsers but the left panel would still expand. You have to weigh your options but I think this one leads to you keeping your sanity down the line.

Here is a demo I made up: http://jsbin.com/siyejeqa/3/edit?css,js,output

You'll have to add the prefixes for other browsers on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this fiiddle [animated div](http://jsfiddle.net/kostisalex/TkRw2/1/)
The whole idea is based on float:left and the **animate()** function.

```
$( ".left" ).animate({
        width: "75%"
        }, 1500 );
```

while

```
.container {
width:100%;
height: 100%;
position:relative;
 }
```

and

```
.left {
width: 25%;
height: 100%;
background: yellow;
float:left;
}
.mid {
width: 50%;
height: 100%;
background:red;
float:left;
}

.right {
width: 23%;
height: 100%;
background: green;
float:left;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly how I wanted it to work. But when I implemented the code and loaded it in the browser the animation would no work. It just remains static.

Comment: That's because you use a second function inside toggle. If you use the code without the second function, you will observe that onLoading, the toggle is doing well. But if you want the toggle to happen on the user's click event, then you have to create an onclick function that toggles the div.